# Error: 'The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PATCH, DELETE.' accessing a route

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm working on a Laravel project where I want to click an object (meeting) and see its details but I get this error:
[laravel error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuUPw.png)

This is my `home.blade.php` file:

```
<!-- list all the meetings -->
<h3>@lang('Following meetings of '){{ $userName }}</h3>
<div class="row container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex-row flex-nowrap position-relative">
        @forelse ($meetings as $meeting)
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="card card-block zoom">
                @csrf
                <div class="card-body bg-dark">
                    <a href="/meeting/{{ $meeting['id'] }}" class="stretched-link text-white">{{ $meeting['name'] }}</a>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
        @empty
            <h4>No tienes reuniones programadas.</h4>
        @endforelse
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My `web.php`:

```
// GET
Route::get('/home', [MeetingController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/meeting/{id}', [MeetingController::class, 'show'])->name('meeting.show')->whereNumber('id');

Route::get('/lectures', [LectureController::class, 'index'])->name('lectures');
Route::get('/lectures/{id}', [LectureController::class, 'show'])->name('lectures')->whereNumber('id');

// POST
Route::get('/meeting/create', [MeetingController::class, 'create'])->name('create_meeting');
Route::post('/home', [MeetingController::class, 'store'])->name('meeting.store');

Route::get('/lectures/create', [LectureController::class, 'create'])->name('create_lecture');
Route::post('/lectures', [LectureController::class, 'store'])->name('lecture.store');

// PUT or patch
Route::get('/meeting/edit/{id}', [MeetingController::class, 'edit'])->name('meeting.edit');
Route::patch('/meeting/{id}', [MeetingController::class, 'update'])->name('meeting.update');

// DELETE
Route::delete('/meeting/{id}', [MeetingController::class, 'destroy'])->name('meeting.delete');
```

And my `MeetingController.php`

```
public function show($id)
{
    //$meeting = Meeting::find($id);
    return $id;
}
```

Comment: it goes to the last route `Route::patch('/meeting/{id}', [MeetingController::class, 'update'])->name('meeting.update');`

Comment: Have you tried `a href="{{ route('meeting.show', $meeting) }}"` (or similar), i.e. actually using the routes you defined by name, instead of an arbitrary link?

Comment: I just tried and the error is still there

Comment: I've also tried to change both delete and patch methods to: Route::patch('/meetings/{id}'... and Route::delete('/meetings/{id}'... and what I get instead is Error 404 | Not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the meeting id is detected as a string. removes the `where()` to match it and it's better to use `route()` to generate a route.

file `web.php`:

```
...
Route::get('/meeting/{id}', [MeetingController::class, 'show'])->name('meeting.show')
...
```

the blade:

```
<a href="{{ route('meeting.show', $meeting['id']) }}" class="stretched-link text-white">{{ $meeting['name'] }}</a>
```